# JPanel repaint from another class

Tags: java, swing, drawing, jpanel, paintcomponent

I have a JPanel which displays an image. In a separate class, I'm reading from an xml file points. I am firstly creating an arraylist of triangles from these points. However I need to show the triangles on the image, i.e. draw them on! (yes this should be simple). But as these points and triangles are created in another class, I do not seem to be able to draw them on the already-displayed image within the GUI class. I have tried creating a ArrayList in the JPanel itself, which I update and then want to repaint, although it will not let me do this as shown below:

Class

```
triangles = clips.getTriangles();
tempPanel.setTriangles(triangles){
```

JPanel

```
 public void settriangles(ArrayList<Point[]> t){
 triangles = t;
 repaint();
}
```

My only other idea is for the JPanel to have a listener waiting for when triangles are returned, updating the field and hence then repainting.

Any ideas?

Thanks

Edit: Code for Drawing

```
public void settriangles(ArrayList<Point[]> t){
    triangles = t;
    repaint();
}

public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    System.out.println("in paint component");
if (g != null) {
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g;
    try {
        Rectangle back_rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, getWidth(),
                getHeight());
        graphics.setColor(GuiComponentGenerator.GUI_BACKGROUND_COLOUR);
        graphics.fill(back_rect);
        if (image != null) {
            int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * magnification);
            int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * magnification);
            Rectangle image_rect = new Rectangle(offset.x, offset.y,
                    width, height);
            graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
            graphics.draw(image_rect);
            graphics.drawImage(image, offset.x, offset.y, width,
                    height, null);
            graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                    RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            for(int pos = 0; pos < triangles.size(); pos++){
                Point[] current = triangles.get(pos);                   
                ArrayList<Point> current_triangle = new ArrayList<Point>();
                current_triangle.add(current[0]);
                current_triangle.add(current[1]);
                current_triangle.add(current[2]);
                drawRegion(graphics, current_triangle); 
            }
        }
    }

finally {
        graphics.dispose();
}
}



private void drawRegion(Graphics2D graphics, ArrayList<Point> points) {
    graphics.setColor(trans_grey);
    Area area = getArea(points);
    graphics.fill(area);
    graphics.setStroke(new BasicStroke(2));
    graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
    graphics.draw(area);
}

private Area getArea(ArrayList<Point> points) {
    Area area = new Area(getPath(points, true));
    return area;
}

private GeneralPath getPath(ArrayList<Point> points, boolean close_path) {
    GeneralPath path = new GeneralPath();
    Point current_screen_point = calculateScreenPoint(points.get(0));
    path.moveTo(current_screen_point.x, current_screen_point.y);
    for (int point_num = 1; point_num < points.size(); point_num++) {
        current_screen_point = calculateScreenPoint(points.get(point_num));
        path.lineTo(current_screen_point.x, current_screen_point.y);
    }
    if (close_path)
        path.closePath();
    return path;
}

public Point calculateScreenPoint(Point image_point) {
    float h_proportion = (float) image_point.x / (float) image.getWidth();
    float v_proportion = (float) image_point.y / (float) image.getHeight();
    float image_width_in_panel = (float) image.getWidth() * magnification;
    float image_height_in_panel = (float) image.getHeight() * magnification;

    Point on_screen_point = new Point(0, 0);
    on_screen_point.x = offset.x
            + Math.round(h_proportion * image_width_in_panel);
    on_screen_point.y = offset.y
            + Math.round(v_proportion * image_height_in_panel);
    return on_screen_point;
}
```

Comment: where do you explicitly draw them ?

Comment: And how did you draw them?  As Images or directly to the Graphics2D

Comment: @MimiEAM I explicitly draw them within the JPanel directly using Graphics2D, hence I update the triangles in JPanel and then need to use repaint somehow

Comment: @redrubia show us the code where you draw them plz

Comment: @MadProgrammer Added the code for drawing, using Java2D

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I worked out how to draw triangles on the image, when passing through an arrayList, where each Point[] represents the points of the triangle.

Note that this is now in a single entire class which is passed the information, rather than trying to call repaint from another class.

```
public AnnotatedDisplayTriangles(BufferedImage image, String image_path, ArrayList<Point[]> triangles) {

    this.image = image;
    this.image_path = image_path;
    this.triangles = triangles;

}

protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    super.paintComponent(g);
    // Draw image centered.
    int x = (getWidth() - image.getWidth())/2;
    int y = (getHeight() - image.getHeight())/2;
    g.drawImage(image, x, y, this);

    Stroke drawingStroke = new BasicStroke(2);
    Graphics2D graph = (Graphics2D)g;
    graph.setStroke(drawingStroke);
    graph.setPaint(Color.black);


    for(int p = 0; p < triangles.size(); p++){

        Point[] current_triangles = triangles.get(p);

        for(int triangle = 0; triangle < current_triangles.length; triangle++ ){

            Point current = current_triangles[triangle];
            Point next;
            if(triangle == current_triangles.length -1 )
                next = current_triangles[0];
            else
                next = current_triangles[triangle + 1];

            Line2D line = new Line2D.Double(current.x, current.y, next.x, next.y);
            graph.draw(line);

        }
    }
}

public static void main(String image_path,ArrayList<Point[]> triangles, String panel_name) throws IOException {
    String path = image_path;
    BufferedImage image = ImageIO.read(new File(path));
    AnnotatedDisplayTriangles contentPane = new AnnotatedDisplayTriangles(image, path, triangles);
    // You'll want to be sure this component is opaque
    // since it is required for contentPanes. Some
    // LAFs may use non-opaque components.
    contentPane.setOpaque(true);

    int w = image.getWidth();
    int h = image.getHeight();

    JFrame f = new JFrame(panel_name);
//  f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    f.setContentPane(contentPane);
    f.setSize(w,h);
    f.setLocation(200,200);
    f.setVisible(true);
}
```

Answer (score 3):

Your `paintComponent` leaves a little to be desired ;)

Firstly, you should never get a null graphics unless the `paint` method has been called in correctly, which in case they deserve for it to fail.

You should try and use `Graphics.create` to create a copy of the incoming `Graphics` context.  This allows you to mess with the `Graphics` properties (such as transforms etc) without adversly effecting the original

I don't know what the `image` is all about, but basically, if its `null`, your triangles will never paint (don't know if this is what you want or not).

I don't know what the `offset` relates to, but just in case, the 0x0 point is always the top, left corner of your component.

[image: Triangles in the sky]

```
public void paintComponent(Graphics g) {

    // This is important, you will to have a very good reason not to call this
    super.paintComponent(g);

    System.out.println("in paint component");
    // Should never need this.  You should never call the paintComponent
    // directly.
    // if (g != null) {
    // Create a copy of the graphics, with which you can play...
    Graphics2D graphics = (Graphics2D) g.create();
    try {
        Rectangle back_rect = new Rectangle(0, 0, getWidth(),
                        getHeight());
        graphics.setColor(Color.GREEN);
        graphics.fill(back_rect);
        // What's this trying to do...
        // Where do you produce this???
        // Because I didn't know where the image was been produced
        // I commented out the code, but you should be aware
        // That if the image is null, you triangles will never paint...
//            if (image != null) {
//                int width = Math.round(image.getWidth() * magnification);
//                int height = Math.round(image.getHeight() * magnification);
//                
//                Rectangle image_rect = new Rectangle(offset.x, offset.y,
//                                width, height);
//                graphics.setColor(Color.BLACK);
//                graphics.draw(image_rect);
//                graphics.drawImage(image, offset.x, offset.y, width,
//                                height, null);
            graphics.setRenderingHint(RenderingHints.KEY_ANTIALIASING,
                            RenderingHints.VALUE_ANTIALIAS_ON);
            for (int pos = 0; pos < triangles.size(); pos++) {
                Point[] current = triangles.get(pos);
                ArrayList<Point> current_triangle = new ArrayList<Point>(3);
                current_triangle.add(current[0]);
                current_triangle.add(current[1]);
                current_triangle.add(current[2]);
                drawRegion(graphics, current_triangle);
            }
        //} // From the image != null
    } finally {
        graphics.dispose();
    }
}
```

I'd also suggest you have a read through

- [2D Graphics](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/index.html)
- [Performing Custom Painting in Swing](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/)

If you haven't already ;)

Comment: Thanks! Looks much better, but my issue is that another class needs to update the image panel, and hence make the triangles draw ontop! The image is being produced within this panel when initiated it is set and shown (this part works :) )

Comment: If you need it to overlay, set this panel as transparent (setOpaque(false))

Answer (score 2):

This article will give you all the info you need  http://java.sun.com/products/jfc/tsc/articles/painting/

but I think you are missing  - 
super.paintComponent(g);

```
public class MyPanel extends JPanel {
    protected void paintComponent(Graphics g) {
    // Let UI delegate paint first 
    // (including background filling, if I'm opaque)
    super.paintComponent(g); 
    // paint my contents next....
    }
}
```