# Triangle Draw Method

Tags: java, swing, awt, graphics2d

I have trouble drawing a triangle with the `draw(Graphics g)` method in Java.
I can draw a rectangle like so:

```
public void draw(Graphics g) {
    g.setColor(colorFill);
    g.fillRect(p.x, p.y, width, height);
    g.setColor(colorBorder);
    g.drawRect(p.x, p.y, width, height);
    drawHandles(g);
```

Where p represents "the top left corner of the shapes". How would I draw the triangle in the same manner?

Could someone give me an example for a standard triangle?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

There is not a drawTriangle method neither in Graphics nor Graphics2D. You need to do it by yourself. You can draw three lines using the `drawLine` method or use one these methods:

- [drawPolygon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolygon%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%29)(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int nPoints)
- [drawPolygon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolygon%28java.awt.Polygon%29)([Polygon](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Polygon.html) p)
- [drawPolyline](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Graphics.html#drawPolyline%28int%5B%5D,%20int%5B%5D,%20int%29)(int[] xPoints, int[] yPoints, int nPoints)

These methods work with polygons. You may change the prefix `draw` to `fill` when you want to fill the polygon defined by the point set. I inserted the documentation links. Take a look to learn how to use them.

There is the [GeneralPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/GeneralPath.html) class too. It can be used with Graphics2D, which is capable to draw [Shapes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Shape.html). Take a look:

- http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/arbitrary.html

Answer (score 3):

You should try using the `Shape`s API.

Take a look at [JPanel repaint from another class](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11917938/jpanel-repaint-from-another-class#comment15869588_11917938) which is all about drawing triangles, look to the `getPath` method for some ideas

You should also read up on [GeneralPath](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/GeneralPath.html) & [Drawing Arbitrary Shapes](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/2d/geometry/arbitrary.html).

This method is much easy to apply [AffineTransformation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/geom/AffineTransform.html)s to

Answer (score 1):

Use a line algorithm to connect point A with point C, and in an outer loop, let point A wander towards point B with the same line algorithm and with the wandering coordinates, repeat drawing that line. You can probably also include a z delta with which is also incremented iteratively. For the line algorithm, just calculate two or three slopes for the delta change of each coordinate and set one slope to 1 after changing the two others proportionally so they are below 1. This is very important for drawing closed geometrical areas between connected mesh particles. Take a look at the Qt Elastic Nodes example and now imagine drawing triangles between the nodes after stretching this over a skeleton.
[As long as it will remain online](http://www.filedropper.com/triangle)

Answer (score 0):

there is no command directly to draw Triangle. For Drawing of triangle we have to use the concept of lines here.

i.e, g.drawLines(Coordinates of points)

Answer (score 0):

There is no direct method to draw a triangle.
You can use drawPolygon() method for this.
It takes three parameters in the following form:
`drawPolygon(int x[],int y[], int number_of_points);`
To draw a triangle:
(Specify the x coordinates in array x and y coordinates in array y and number of points which will be equal to the elements of both the arrays.Like in triangle you will have 3 x coordinates and 3 y coordinates which means you have 3 points in total.)
Suppose you want to draw the triangle using the following points:`(100,50),(70,100),(130,100)`
Do the following inside `public void paint(Graphics g)`:

```
int x[]={100,70,130};
int y[]={50,100,100};
g.drawPolygon(x,y,3);
```

Similarly you can draw any shape using as many points as you want.

Answer (score -1):

You can use Processing library:
https://processing.org/reference/PGraphics.html

There is a method called triangle():

```
g.triangle(x1,y1,x2,y2,x3,y3)
```